# How to find total amount from a string using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Hi i am working on a ruby on rails project wih ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I have a string which contains the total amount. So i need to find the total amount using regex.

```
String:-
"TOTAL 
EFT 
CHANGE 
Taxable Ite.s 
TOTAL includes GST 
OTHER SAVINGS 
0000000000 
$73.26 
HAIERF(RDS stm IGA 
KARAWARA *AOI 
TERMINAL"
```

Here $73.26 is the total amount. I tried `/$(\d{1,2}(\.)\d{1,2})/` and  `/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/`  But its not working. Please help me with exact regex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to escape `$`...

Comment: How to escape?.

Comment: Like what you did to dot.

Comment: /\$(\d{1,2}(\.)\d{1,2})/ is it correct?

Comment: Can you please modify it?

Comment: I laso tried /^\d{1,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/ but it returns nil

Comment: This `/\$(\d{1,2}(\.)\d{1,2})/` was correct. See it in action http://rubular.com/r/ceMfAXotJ7

Answer (score 1):

Updated As per the op's comment:

```
/TOTAL(?=((?!TOTAL).)*).*?(\$\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)/im
```

This is a compilation of both of your regex.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/PuGrqn/2)

**Sample Source** ( [**Run Here**](https://ideone.com/5IHRIc) )

```
re = /TOTAL(?=((?!TOTAL).)*).*?(\$\d{1,4}(?:\.\d{1,2})?)/im
str = 'TOTAL   $234
EFT 
CHANGE 
Taxable Ite.s 
TOTAL includes GST 
OTHER SAVINGS 
0000000000 
$73.26 
HAIERF(RDS stm IGA 
KARAWARA *AOI 
TERMINAL
$83.26

Total
asdasfd
sadfasdf
$1235
'
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match[1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks is there any way so that regex search only after the Total keyword? as there may be many amount with dollar symbol before Total keyword so i want to search only after the Total keyword.

Comment: cant there be more `total` as well?

Comment: Yes there can be more total but i want after the first Total. is it possible?

Comment: Checkout the answer

Comment: Thanks let me try this.